# Are background images wrapped in media queries loaded after the default background image?

Tags: css, retina-display

I want to add a background that will **render progressively on high res devices**

**Will the smaller (non-retina / high-res) image load before the high res - when the smaller image is the default background (before the media query)?**

```
.element
   background-image: url(image-1x.png)
   background-size: cover

  @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
     background-image: url(image-2x.png)
```

A reference to CSS specifications for this is most appreciated.

Comment: While it wont give you a "per the spec" answer, you could test what browsers are actually doing with the devtools network tab and just see which images are requested.

Comment: @DBS it's a fair point. to be able to test it fully I'd need to have 2 media queries changing on the fly or that sort. but yes, it seems they are loaded in order at least (if I don't use any media query at all but just 2 backgrounds in a sequence)

Comment: I would presume not, as all rules are evaluated before initiating any actual loading of resources, and at no point will that final value of `background-image` ever be both values or an older value that does not apply anymore?

Comment: indeed the final value will be only 1. Ultimately it does download both images though. It would be great if there was some sort of official documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know how CSS Cascade works.
[MDN article here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade)
[Spec here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/)

In your particular case, I'd suggest to replace `@media` with
`-webkit-image-set`:

```
.element {    
    background-image: url(image-1x.png); 
    background-image: -webkit-image-set(
                         url(image-1x.png) 1x,
                         url(image-2x.png) 2x
                      );
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I can't find any reference to `-webkit-image-set` in any of the links you added (or even Google)

Comment: though I could find an image-set here which is likely what you meant https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set . yet I don't understand how it relates to CSS Cascade?

Comment: @dragonmnl, cascade explains how rules are being applied. `image-set` helps you to avoid `@media` query. The prefixed `-webkit-image-set` version is what you need to be workig in [most browsers' versions](https://caniuse.com/css-image-set) not only in the latest ones. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Kosh! Now it's clear